# how to insert (C#) variables in xml

Tags: c#, xml

if i were to say create a function:

```
public static string createProduct(string pName, decimal pPrice)
{string postData = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?
                     <product>
                         <name>?</name>
                         <price>?</price>
                     </product>";
....some other codes...}
```

i have tried googling it but have not found any clear answer...
and sorry i'm kinda new to xml and c#, so how do i insert pName and pPrice into xml without upsetting visual studio?

would really appreciate help from you guys...tia!

Comment: Have you looked into **String.Format** before asking this question?  Your question shows a complete lack of research on your part.  The construction of a string in C# is a very simple task.

Comment: very sorry of the noob question...i will look into that,thank you!

Comment: If you're representing objects in your code with XML, I'd recommend looking into XML Serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = new XElement("product", 
                    new XElement("name", pName), 
                    new XElement("price", pPrice))
          .ToString();
```

[System.Xml.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx)  and [XElement class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) are good places to start to read and easier to use than [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) namespace

Comment: +1 Very nice, good answer. Since the OP is a self-proclaimed beginner you may want to explain what exactly the code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string createProduct(string pName, decimal pPrice)
{string postData = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?
                     <product>
                         <name>" + pName + @"</name>
                         <price>" + pPrice+ @"</price>
                     </product>";
....some other codes...}
```

**I recommend that you take a look at constructing the XML document not by string concatenation as it is quite unreliable (what if pName contains angle brackets?). Try looking at the XElement (XLINQ) API.**

Comment: This has the potential to make the entire XML document not well-formed or otherwise invalid depending upon the inputs. I wouldn't recommend this solution; OP should be working against the XML DOM instead. Also, you're introducing `@` within the XML - did you intend to do that?

Comment: The at sign was an error, thanks. I bolded my warning text because I fully agree with you. Yet, I think it is best to always give a direct answer too. Just saying "you shouldn't do that" is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for `how to add variables to a string in c#` yielded this page as the first result: [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings (that compiles to the `string.Concat` method).  Or, you could use `string.Format`; for more information on that, see the page on [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).  This approach is only suitable for the simplest of small XML fragments.

You also have several options in the form of different sets of classes that will help you build and work with XML, most of which are to be found in the [System.Xml namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145036.aspx).  These classes will produce well-formed XML, taking care of small details that you might overlook (for example, special handling of certain characters).  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good discussion of the pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend not doing this by string concatenation. There are a number of different ways to accomplish this that will yield better (as in less likely to produce malformed XML) results.

Via [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx):

```
string xmlString = null;

using (StringWriter xmlOutput = new StringWriter())
using(XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlOutput))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("product");
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("name", pName);
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("price", pPrice);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlString = xmlOutput.ToString();
}
```

Using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx):

```
    string xmlString = null;

    using (StringWriter xmlOutput = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement productElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("product");

        XmlElement nameElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("name");
        nameElement.InnerText = pName;

        XmlElement priceElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("price");
        priceElement.InnerText = pPrice;

        productElement.AppendChild(nameElement);
        productElement.AppendChild(priceElement);
        xmlDocument.AppendChild(productElement);

        xmlDocument.Save(xmlOutput);

        xmlString = xmlOutput.ToString();
    }
```

Using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (requires that you are using .NET 3.5 or higher):

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(
                              new XElement("product",
                                                     new XElement("name", pName),
                                                     new XElement("price", pPrice)
                                          )
                             );

string xmlString = xml.ToString();
```

Note that of these methods only the one using XmlTextWriter will stream, which may be important for very large XML composition. If you are using .NET 3.5 or higher and are not dealing with very large XML composition, I would give preference to XDocument as it's a lot more readable and simpler to use.